# How to enable read more by default using jquery

Tags: jquery, read-more

I have a [question and answer](https://askpuzzle.com) website and using a custom wordpress theme, which has the option to enable **read more** link using jquery. When i click on read more link, it expands full content of the post without opening the post.

I want to know if it is possible to expand the post by default without clicking on red more link. Could you please help me to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution bellow with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".post-read-more").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).click();
        });
        // And if you want to finally disable this links
        jQuery(".question-read-more").remove();
        jQuery(".question-read-less").remove();
    });
```

Bests,
Camille

Comment: Thanks for the help. May i know where and how exactly i need to add this code. I have no prior experience of modifying jQuery. I see a folder called JS for java script inside theme and there are several files. Sorry for basic question.